# Any Legit way to Obtain a Shiny Zygarde?

Tags: pokemon-series

Is there *any* way to obtain a shiny Zygarde legitimately? If not, is anybody willing to trade for one? I'll post my friend code if so. Thank you!

Comment: Please look up your question before posting it here. I found the answer in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Zygarde is [shiny locked](https://shiny-pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Shiny-Locked_Pokemon), meaning that there is no way to catch a shiny Zygarde.

There was a limited time gift in 2018 that allowed you to get a shiny Zygarde but these codes can no longer be redeemed.

The only way to get a shiny Zygarde is by trading but since it's now impossible to get a shiny Zygarde it would be very hard to find someone willing to trade theirs.

Answer (score 2):

Other than getting it from the [June 2018 event](https://www.usgamer.net/articles/how-to-get-shiny-zygarde-in-pokemon-ultra-sun-and-moon), Shiny Zygarde can be found randomly in [Dynamax Adventures](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/dynamaxadventures.shtml). Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/Q9MrTOgUeJg?t=703) of someone getting one.

Comment: Beating Zygarde in Dynamax Adventures is an achievement of its own because of Phase 2 (Power Construct). Lucky them (the person in the video).